# Plotting points above surface

Tags: plotting

If I use

```
Show[
 Plot3D[y^2 - x^2 y - x y, {x, -1.1, 0.2}, {y, -0.2, 0.1}],
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.03], 
   Point[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {-0.5, -0.125, -1/64}}]}]
 ]
```

[image]

The points are not quite visible, or approximately half the point is visible, since it sinks in the surface. Is there a way to draw the point, but the circle, by which the point is represented, is fully visible? In addition, how do I print text above point, e.g. P_1, P_2, P_3?

Comment: On a side note, I think plotting the spheres on top of the plot might be confusing, because they _should_ be partially hidden.

Comment: To make the points more visible, reduce the `Opacity` of the `Plot3D` with something like `PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4]`

Answer (score 3):

```
pointcoords = {{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {-0.5, -0.125, -1/64}}; 

Show[Plot3D[y^2 - x^2 y - x y, {x, -1.1, 0.2}, {y, -0.2, 0.1}], 
 Graphics3D[Text[Style["●", 16], #] & /@ pointcoords]]
```

[image]

#### [Text >> Details and Options:](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I like a combination of `Opacity` and color contrast (so you can see that half of each point is below the surface):

[image]

```
Show[Plot3D[y^2 - x^2 y - x y, 
       {x, -1.1, 0.2}, {y, -0.2, 0.1},
       PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6]], 
     Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize[.03], 
      Point[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, 
            {-0.5, -0.125, -1/64}}]}]]
```